# Change column class of div in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've found a number of similar questions but cannot seem to get their solutions to work for me so hopefully posting the specific code will help.

I use Caspio datapages deployed on html pages. On an html page I have a full 12 column div that I need to change to a 9 column div when a link is clicked on. This is because I have a collapsed 3 column div that is opened when the link is clicked.

So what i need:

> 1) upon page load 3 column div collapsed, 12 column div visible.
>
> 2)user clicks link and 3 column div is visible and 12 column div changes
>   to 9 column div so it is moved to the right of the 3 column div
>   instead of below it.

The Caspio datapages can get messed up if the css is intense (is random when it happens so I can't describe it in detail) so I need to keep it as simple as possible. If I could change div `class="col-md-12"` to div `class="col-md-9"` on the link click that would be great. I've seen other posts with changing column classes but I cannot seem to get them to work.

Here's the main code I'm working with:

```html
<div class="col-md-3" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow=y:hidden;">
 <div id="newcomment" class="collapse">
  <caspio deploy code for datapage1>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div>
  <caspio deploy code for datapage2>
 </div>
</div>

<a class="btn page-action" href="#newcomment" style="color:green;" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Comment</a>
```

So if I can change div `class="col-md-12"` to div `class="col-md-9"` upon the `#newcomment` link click that should probably do it. Many thanks in advance-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. Here is one...

```
$('#btnSwitch').click(function(){
    $('.col-md-3').toggleClass('hide');
    $('#right').toggleClass('col-md-12 col-md-9');
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
                page1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" id="right">
                page2
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg" id="btnSwitch">Switch</button>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/pFNLZqoZUV

Comment: This looks really good- many thanks. I just need it to go in reverse order. Meaning have the page 2 div normally show at 12 columns (and page 1 div hidden) on page load. Then when button is clicked show page 1 div (col 3) and convert page 2 div to col 9. I'm playing around with the script but can't seem to get it right. Is there a quick switch on that?

Comment: ok I did get it to work using "collapse" and then switching the script. that's really great and thanks very much for this simple, elegant solution.

Comment: Sorry bout that- I don't see where to 'accept' the answer. This is my first post on SO. I'll look for it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Realized the check mark was the accept link- would be easier for first time people if there were the word 'accept' by it. as it is, got it going forward and thanks for the help.